ArcGIS Pro Feature to Point attribute inconsistency
I'm curious to see if anyone has run into an issue where the ArcGIS Pro Feature to Point tool has generated inconsistent data?  I have a set of polygons that I'm use to collect zonal statistics. I need to use the centroids to collect other data for the work.  There are two columns of attribute data in the polygon feature set.  The Site_ID_Li column corresponds to a site number and I'm using a user created column called ORIG_FID at a later step to link up the polygon and point datasets.
I ran the Feature to Point tool on the polygon features, selected "inside" and made sure that everything is in the same projection.  Trouble is, ORIG_FID field is shuffled about and a join on that should show Feature 38BK2026 4 is joined to a different point Feature, i.e., 38BK815 4, when 38BK815 had an original ORIG_FID value of 23.  I've already worked around the issue by generating points from the polygon centroids. I'm just looking to understand if anyone has seen similar behavior?
